# Web2py: translate controller names and function names

Tags: routes, url-routing, translation, web2py

In [web2py](http://web2py.com/) I'm using the [Parameter-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Parameter-based-system) and I would like to find a strategy to **translate controller names and function names**.

I have 2 domains and I use only one app for both, but I would like to have the controllers and functions translated for the non-english one.

Something like this:

- http://domain.com/article/new (english - default language)
- http://domain.pt/artigo/novo  (portuguese - translation)

What would be the best way to achieve this?

PS: I also would like to have some redirection if someone typed the wrong domain extension:
http://domain.pt/article/new -> http://domain.pt/artigo/novo

Answer (score 0):

Francisco,

You'll have to do something in web2py's routes.py (http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#URL-rewrite) where you'll rewrite your URL's according to the clients language.

ps.: Anyway, i don't know if that's the right approach, since i never saw any web application doing what you're trying to accomplish.